# Congruence of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Let $X=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&0&0\\ c&d&0&0\\0&0&-a&-b\\0&0&-c&-d\end{bmatrix}$  where $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}$.

For a such given $X$, is there a $4\times 4$ matrix $P$ over $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficient satisfying the following?

- $\operatorname{det}(P)=\pm 1$
- $PXP^T=\begin{bmatrix} O&A\\B&O\end{bmatrix}$ where $A, B,O$ are $2\times 2 $ matrices and $O$ is the matrix with zero entries.

Answer (score 0):

Try
$$
P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{matrix} 
I&I\\ I&-I
\end{matrix}\right),
$$
where $I$ is the $2\times 2$ unit matrix.

It should be $P^{-1}=P$ and $PXP=\left(\begin{matrix} 
0&A\\ A&0
\end{matrix}\right)$, with $A=\left(\begin{matrix} 
a&b\\ c&d
\end{matrix}\right)$.

Comment: Well, then $PXP^T=\begin{bmatrix}-a&-b&0&0\\-c&-d&0&0\\0&0&a&b\\0&0&c&d\end{bmatrix}$. So, I don't think your $P$ works...

Comment: @BillGrey: See edited version.

Comment: Well.. I want $P$ is a matrix over $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficient.

Comment: You can adjust $P$ to have rational coefficients here and determinant $\pm 1$, but not with integer coefficients.